# How to select all files in a multiChoiceDialog

Tags: python, dialog, wxpython

It's not apparent to me how to execute a select all checkbox in a MultiChoice Dialog widget. Does anybody have any experience or can someone offer some direction in accomplishing this task? Thanks.

Below is working code for the dialog:

```
sampleList = []
    for filename in filelist:
       (head, filename) = os.path.split(filename)
       if filename.endswith(".log") or filename.endswith(".txt"):
            sampleList.append(filename)


    dlg = wx.MultiChoiceDialog(
           self, "Files in c:\Extracted", 'Local File Search',
           sampleList,
           wx.CHOICEDLG_STYLE
           )

    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        cur_item = dlg.GetSelections()
        strings = [sampleList[x] for x in cur_item]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's really possible with this kind of dialog. What you should do instead is create a custom dialog with the wx.Dialog class and put some checkbox widgets in it. To my knowledge, there is no way to attach wx.EVT_CHECKBOX to the checkbox's in that default dialog.

Comment: Creating a custom dialog to look similar to the above dialog, I'm more than likely going to need a textcontrol to display the items in the list (files in a path)?